# Ошибка активация касперского

Tags: активация

Доброго времени суток! У меня возникла проблема с касперским 2013. Пытаюсь вводить код активации и вываливает ошибку "Ошибка активации: Не удается определить адрес сервера". На официальные сайты касперского тоже не заходит. Судя по всему вирусы блокируют все это дело.  Проверял файл hosts но там все чисто. Подскажите как победить вирусы в данной ситуации, когда лицензия истекла на касперский и продлить через код или ключ не удается его?

Answer (score 1):

Если есть ключевой файл, то c:/...../avp.com addkey c:/....../number.key  если нет ключа а только код, то предварительно пролечить drweb.cureit, или аналогичными утилитами Касперского - скачать на другом девайсе и перенести через флешку , CD или другим способом.